# how to show error note for only when a particular object value is empty in text field in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Objective is to show error to the particular object id when we dont enter any value in the textfield in onChange method. But it is appearing in the other id text field.

JSON data looks in this way:

```
"details": [
      { "id": "12wer1", "name": "ABC", "age": 15 },
      { "id": "78hbg5", "name": "FRE", "age": 21 }
    ]
```

I've tried in this way:

```
{this.state.details.map((y) => (
              <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <TextField label="Name" name="dName" variant="outlined" value={y.name}
 onChange={(e)=>this.onChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                  <TextField label="Age" name="age"variant="outlined" value={y.age} onChange={(e)=>this.onChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)}/>
 <FormHelperText >
                                        {this.state.errors.age}
                                    </FormHelperText>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            ))}
```

OnChange method:

```
onChange = (name, value)=> {

this.state.details.forEach((item) => {
                    if (!item.age) {
                        errors.age = "age is required";
                    }
                    else {
                        errors.age = ""
                    }


}
```

I'm getting error in other ids also. for example i want to clear the age for 1st id then error is showing on both the ids.

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will have to something like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, FormHelperText } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      details: [
        { id: "12wer1", name: "ABC", age: 15 },
        { id: "78hbg5", name: "FRE", age: 21 }
      ],
      errors: {
        name: {},
        age: {}
      }
    };

    this.onNameChange = this.onChange.bind(this, "name");
    this.onAgeChange = this.onChange.bind(this, "age");
  }

  onChange = (property, id, e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let { details, errors } = this.state;
    details.forEach((d) => {
      if (d.id === id) {
        d[property] = value;
        errors[property][id] = value === "" ? `${property} is required` : "";
      }
    });

    console.log(errors);

    this.setState({
      details: details,
      errors: errors
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.details.map((y) => (
          <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <TextField
                label="Name"
                name="dName"
                variant="outlined"
                value={y.name}
                onChange={(e) => this.onNameChange(y.id, e)}
              />
              <FormHelperText>
                {this.state.errors.name[y.id] || ""}
              </FormHelperText>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
              <TextField
                label="Age"
                name="age"
                variant="outlined"
                value={y.age}
                onChange={(e) => this.onAgeChange(y.id, e)}
              />
              <FormHelperText>
                {this.state.errors.age[y.id] || ""}
              </FormHelperText>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

We basically have to link each error's object with it's specific rendered element.
Here is the running code for the same: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hopper-k86xq?file=/src/App.js)